# finding latest version files in each directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, command

I have files with versions, i.e. 2 digit suffixes for each file

> ex: dphy/05E2.01, dphy/05E2.00, pll/05E2.43, pll/05E2.42 ...

I am writing a script to process these files. Could able to list, only versioned files with below command

```
find /path/ -type f -name '*.[0-9][0-9]'
```

But I am interested in only latest versions of files from each directory i.e.

> dphy/05E2.01, pll/05E2.43

So, how to list only latest versions?

Comment: I recommend writing a bash script that can perform some arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /path/ -type f -name '*.[0-9][0-9]' |
awk -F '.' '{k=$0; sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", k)} $NF>=max[k]{max[k]=$NF} 
      END{for (i in max) print i FS max[i]}'

/path/pll/05E2.43
/path/dphy/05E2.01
```

Comment: It is listing latest file versions but non-version file also exists along with version files `dphy/6P, dphy/05E2.01`, so `find` listing them also

Comment: It's working, but displayed this if only one version existed `hdmidprx/05E2.`, also please explain `awk` statement

Comment: `awk` command splits on DOT thus keeping part after last DOT in last field. Then in first block we use `sub` function call to create a key **without** part after last DOT. Then in next block we compare each version number to the max version number i.e. `$NF>max[k]`. If we get a number greater than what we have in `max` array we store that using `max[k]=$NF`. Finally in `END` block we print each entry